# Why AngularJS re-triggers 'link' function of custom directive when model changed?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/01BRRI?p=preview

**Purpose:** build a directive that edits data and save back to controller scope.

**Code description:**

$scope.object is data in controller, I referenced it in directive by using '=' in isolate scope definition. I want to edit it in directive and save it back to controller.

**Problem:**

Input field would be blurred after any value change. In console you'll find the 'link' function is re-triggered after model value changed. (When model="object.meta[key][index]" in line 41).

If you comment out line 40, 42 and edit 41 to: `<editable model="object.meta[key][0]"></editable>`

Then everything is right (1. Link function is not re-triggered. 2. Input is not blurred after model change. 3. Controller $scope.object is updated).

I need the nested loop for my data structure, how should I do to fix this?

Comment: The code is supposed to be right here, in your question.

Comment: No, it has problem: when you edit any input field, input blurs. And that's not a DOM event problem mentioned by sss. Input blurs because 'link' was fire again, and it should not be.

Answer (score 1):

Input blurs because every time when you updating model `ng-repeater` re-redndering DOM.
To prove that please see that example http://plnkr.co/edit/THJd8z?p=preview
I've used there angular 1.3 which support futers called `Bind Once` more info you can find here http://swirlycheetah.com/native-bind-once-in-angularjs-1-3/

```
 <section ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, values) in ::object.meta">
      <div ng-repeat="(index, value) in ::values">
        <editable model="object.meta[key][index]"></editable>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{object}}
  </section>
```